# Prevent Custom file Reading

Tags: c#, serialization, filereader

How can I prevent some application to read my custom file?

Ex: I have a custom file called `file.pp`

I want my c# application to only read what's inside of file.pp .

If notepad++ opens it , it will show garbage data.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: The term you're looking for is obfuscation. Search for `c# obfuscate text` and there are lots of examples.

Comment: Define "garbage data".  Whatever data you put in the file will be the data in the file.

Comment: Encrypt the file's content. Only your application knows the password

Comment: garbage data means .. other text that is not the real data..

Comment: @Equalsk i will try to search for that one ...

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko   yeah that is a good idea..  thanks!

Comment: Who do you want to protect this data from? How secure do you want it to be? If you store both the encryption algorithm and the key on the machine, the file is not safe from a malicious user.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this last by writing directly an object inside your `file.pp` .

So , you'ill create a Model class that will be stored in the file as Object ,
then you can add or read all added Object by using the `BinaryFormatter` `serialization` `desieralisation` ( and loop throw added aobject )

by opening the file you'll see only binary data , only your App or mapped Model can read it :)

See this [Online Sample](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMM2g1cUQyNnpKRDA) in which I've created `MyObjectModel` , and write every execution  a `List` of `MyObject` to file.pp then read all added values

Comment: _"only your App or mapped Model can read it :)"_ - nope, anyone can read it, they just have to decompile the app and recompile the reading part and the types used into a separate application with the same assembly name.

Comment: Yes sur , that's why I've said `or mapped Model can read it :)` in which I meant this case :D

Comment: You may have to start by explaining what you mean by "mapped model" then.

Comment: Yep , you're right , I wrongly formulated my sentence . should explain first :)